# malloc not fail in Keil C

Tags: c, keil, 8051

How can i check whether malloc() was fail in Keil C?

```
unsigned char xdata malloc_mempool [0x100];
void display()
{
    unsigned char xdata *ptr;
    int a;
    init_mempool (&malloc_mempool, sizeof(malloc_mempool));

    ptr = malloc(9000000);
    if(ptr != 0)
    {
        a = 7;
        free(ptr);
    } else {
        a = 9;
    }
}
```

As stated in http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_malloc.htm
malloc will return null pointer if there is not enough memory to satisfy the allocation request. It is obviously not so mush memory in 8051. But the result of a is always 7.

Comment: `9000000` doesn't even fit into an int. I don't remember by heart what the compiler is supposed to do in this case, but you might want to change this into a value < 65536. Am I right to suppose that `int` is 16 bit in your case?

Comment: @glglgl, `malloc()` takes an `unsigned int` though.

Comment: How much RAM does your device actually have?

Comment: From [this table](http://www.keil.com/boards/8051.asp) one can tell it's definitely below 8.5 MB.

Comment: What's the size of an `int` on your platform?

Comment: The result is the same for malloc(9000).(In the range of int).

Comment: @mingpepe And how much RAM does your device have ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz RAM size shouldn't matter - `malloc` only takes as much as provided with `init_mempool()`, so for the sake of this queation, 256 Bytes.

Comment: @mingpepe try: `for (;;) 
{
  unsigned char xdata *ptr;
  ptr = malloc(1000);
  if (ptr == NULL)
    crash();
}`. With this `crash()` should be called at some point.

Comment: Maybe there is a minimum for the size of the mempool. 256 bytes is really very low.

Comment: @Abbondanza As `unsigned int` and `int` have the same sizes, a system with 16 bit `int` has also 16 bit `unsigned int`, where the limit is 65535.

Comment: @MichaelWalz sizeof(int) = 2 and RAM=512 bytes, but it seems not matter. And the code does not execute the crash()

Comment: @mingpepe look at the source code of `malloc`. BTW does it make sense to have dynamic memory allocation on a system with 512 bytes of RAM ?

Comment: @mingpepe You could try displaying the value of `ptr` in order to maybe get an idea of why it doesn't work

Comment: @mingpepe, why is there still `9000000` in your example code? Update it to be a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What exactly is returned in `ptr`? What happens when you try to read from/write to the memory `malloc()` claims to have allocated?

Comment: "But the result of a is always 7." --> Perhaps since code does nothing with `a` that `a` is optimized.  OP's assertion that `a` is 7 is based upon reading `a` in an unstated method.  Make real code that prints the value of `a`. and the value of `ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

From [Understanding The Memory Organization Of 8051 Microcontroller](http://www.multisoftvirtualacademy.com/blog/understanding-the-memory-organization-of-8051-microcontroller/) the 8051 has a maximum 64KB of memory.

So it will be using 2 bytes for pointers. 9000000 decimal is 0x895440 in hex, which is 3 bytes.

Very probably the malloc() function will just ignore the bits it cannot use, so in reality the call you are making is

```
ptr = malloc(0x5440);
```

which is

```
ptr = malloc(21568);
```

Comment: Probably correct, but that still doesn't answer why it doesn't work with `malloc(9000)` (see comments).

Comment: Er, yes it does. The question says " the result of a is always 7." which means malloc allocated memory successfully. If you get the same result with malloc(9000) that is expected.

Comment: @buffjape With a malloc pool of 256 bytes I wouldn't expect that at all.

Comment: OP shouldn't expect others to gather the missing pieces from some comments but [post a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead.